# Error running Hololens Unity Project

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens-emulator

I get the following error when I try to run a hololens Unity3D project through the hololens emulator:

```
Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 0.000000, 0.000000) (Camera rect 0 0 1268 720)

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Camera/Camera.cpp Line: 2622)

The program '[2756] HoloProj.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I'm using Unity 5.6.0f3 and have tried running the build export through VS 2015 and VS 2017, both with and without Admin access.

My coworker also working on this project, but located in India, doesn't have this problem and we have spent several hours trying to resolve it with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I updated Unity from 5.5 to 5.6.

I downgraded the Unity to an older version and it fixed the problem for me.
Give it a try ;)

Comment: That worked! I'm reporting the issue to Unity so they can see if they introduced a bug. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out a bug was in fact introduced.  Bug Report #910047

Comment: The latest unaffected version seems to be 5.5.2